# Why create system call is called creat?

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

Why create system call is called `creat`?

Also, why a define for a buffer size is called `BUFSIZ` and not `BUFSIZE`?

Are there any other such examples?

Related: (taken from comments)
[What did Ken Thompson mean when he said, “I'd spell create with an 'e'.”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10893)

Comment: When Ken Thompson was asked if he redid UNIX, what would he do differently, he said that he'd spell `creat` with an `e`. [source](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Kenneth_Thompson#Attributed).

Comment: See here:

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10893/what-did-ken-thompson-mean-when-he-said-id-spell-create-with-an-e

Specifically the answer by bromfiets.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim Any idea of BUFSIZ?

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim Seems to adhere to the rule of 6 too.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [LSP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009585) (page 28):

> Yes, this function’s name is missing an e. Ken Thompson, the creator
>   of Unix, once joked that the missing letter was his largest regret in
>   the design of Unix.

Comment: What do you mean by LSP?

Comment: @Beginner Linux System Programming. I linked the book in my answer

Comment: @Beginner I've read it some time ago. When I saw your question I searched it for "Ken Thompshon" and voilà.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. "I reget this" isn't "here's why I did this".

Answer (score 15):

Back in the time of [`pdp-11`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11), there was an encoding called [`radix50`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Radix-50), packing three characters (from a limited set) into one 16 bits word. That introduced the limitation of 6 letters for filename and 3 for extension, 6 letters for identifier, etc.

That said, it doesn't explain `creat` in any way.

Comment: Is that what happened to `umount`, though?

Comment: @DanielH, no idea, but cold be the case. Maybe also indirectly — this explains where the tradition to stay within 6-letters boundary originates from.

Comment: My first thought seeing "radix50" above was "50?  How do they fit 3 one-of-50 choices in 16 bits when even three one-of-41 choices won't fit?"  Then I realized how much DEC likes octal.

Comment: @supercat, not just DEC — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal#Usage :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: But it's not called radix050, despite the convention that octal numbers elsewhere seem to be padded to three or six digits (for 8 or 16 bits) and/or have leading zeroes.  Binary-to-character encoding formats seem to prefer decimal in their names, e.g. base64 or base85, rather than base100 or base125, so it seems curious that a radix code wouldn't.

Comment: @supercat, back in the time freedom and creativity were the values in this realm. It was before some certain kind of people that I fail to name came to set the rules, enforce conventions, publish guidelines and establish methodologies…

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: I'm not saying some radix police should have arrested the people who coined the name, but merely expressing surprise that people would have chosen that name rather than a name which would seem less likely to cause confusion.  As for the earlier time, I think the real problem with C is that compilers have lost sight of the fact that when the Standard was published, it was intended to add universally-guaranteed behaviors to existing platforms, not strip away any additional useful behaviors that platforms could and did offer.  C and maybe C++ are the only languages...

Comment: ...I can think of where code for a number of tasks could be written more readably, efficiently, and concisely 20 years ago than today.

Answer (score 7):

My favourite example of the short-name-madness on unixoid systems is the umount command (see the "[Why is 'umount' not spelled 'unmount'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9832/why-is-umount-not-spelled-unmount)" thread over on unix.stackexchange.org for an explanation, once again, a six-letter-limit). It would be very interesting to compare the time saved by having one letter less to type with the time invested for reading manpages and consulting info, over all those thousands of Unix users over the years...

Comment: But the naming was not to save time, it was a hard limit on the length of the name.

Answer (score 4):

You have to remember that memory was very valuable in the old days. It was common for compilers to have very short maximum variable name lengths. I worked on systems with max lengths of 3. Many of the early C compilers limited variable names to 6 characters.

Comment: On a related note, it would be interesting to know how many DB/2 databases in current use still have only 6-letter identifiers.

Comment: What are you talking about? They limited names to 6 characters, sure, but `creat` has 5. `create` would have 6.