# Why cc1 is called cc1?

Tags: c, gcc

The part of the GCC responsible for the compilation of C code calls `cc1`. Where does this name come from?

Comment: From [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390979/why-create-system-call-is-called-creat

Comment: @ beginner: Your point being? Just because questions inappropriate to SO have been asked before, doesn't mean they should be asked again. A *shedload* of off-topic, non-constructive, too-localized, and just outright **bad** questions have been asked and answered on SO. And yet, we should continue to try to keep it on-topic and pragmatic (or change its operating instructions). (To be clear: This isn't bad in any way, just not in line with SO's stated goals.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: If someone shows up who knows the necessary gcc history, it's perfectly answerable. (Heck, I wouldn't be surprised if the answer were just buried in their mailing lists somewhere.) It's not a matter of opinion or debate.

Comment: @duskwuff: Look at the actual quote.

Comment: Are you asking for the origin of the C compiler function, perhaps it's just a naming convention?

Comment: @Link: From what I understand, yes: for instance, `cpp` stands for "C pre-processor"; what, if anything, does the `1` in `cc1` signify?

Answer (score 11):

The 1 in `cc1` indicates that it is the first stage of the build process. The second stage is `collect2`.

Comment: Excellent, you have read my mind and answered the second question of mine. Thanks.